# How to check response time with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-durable-functions

I am using a program that sends HTTP requests and parameters to Azure Functions' Durable functions for processing.

I would like to check the time taken for processing and response time in this program, and I would like to check it in the log of Application Insights, but I don't know how to check it.

How can I find out the response time for each request from the Application Insights logs?

Or, if there is another way to find out the response time for each request other than Application Insights, please let me know.

```py
    import azure.functions as func
    import azure.durable_functions as df
    import logging
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    import sys
    
    app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
    @app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
    @app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
    async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
            activity = int(req.params.get('activity') or req.get_json().get('activity'))
            size = int(req.params.get('size') or req.get_json().get('size'))
    
        instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {"activity": activity, "size": size})
        logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
        await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
        status = await client.get_status(instance_id)
        return f"runtime: {status.runtime_status}\n\noutput: {status.output}" 
    
    
    @app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
    def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> dict:
        parameter = context.get_input()
        activity = int(parameter.get("activity"))
        size = int(parameter.get("size"))
        data_size_list, byte_list, time_list = [], [], []
        
        if activity == 1: #DataFrame
            for i in range(2):        
                result  =  yield context.call_activity("activity1", size)
                data_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result["data"])  # deserialize
                transfer_time  =  time.perf_counter() - result["start"] # Transfer time record when deserialization is finished
                dict_size = sys.getsizeof(result["data"]) # After measuring the transfer time, measure the data size
                dict_size += sum(map(sys.getsizeof, result["data"].values())) + sum(map(sys.getsizeof, result["data"].keys()))

                data_size_list.append(size)
                byte_list.append(dict_size)
                time_list.append(transfer_time)
    
        output = {"data-size": data_size_list, "data-byte": byte_list, "transfer-time": time_list}
        result = yield context.call_activity("write_csv", output)
        return output
    
    # Transfer DataFrame as dictionary type
    @app.activity_trigger(input_name="size")
    def  activity1(size: int) -> dict:
        data = np.random.rand(size) # Create a Numpy array with one row and one column of size
        data  =  pd.DataFrame(data) # Convert Numpy array to Dataframe
        start = time.perf_counter() # The time to convert a Dataframe to a serializable dictionary type is also measured, so it is indicated here.
        data_ = data.to_dict() # Convert to serializable type
        return {"data": data_, "start": start}
    
    # Function to write to csv
    @app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="newblob/result.csv", connection="BlobStorageConnection")
    @app.activity_trigger(input_name="output")
    def  write_csv(output: dict, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
        df = pd.DataFrame(output)
        csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
        outputblob.set(csv_data)
        return "Insersed"
```

Comment: Can you share your program?

Comment: I have included a simplified version of the program I use

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your code like below to get the Response Time and Transfer Time like below:-

***Your updated function_app.py code to receive Transfer time and Response Time:-***

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    activity = int(req.params.get('activity') or req.get_json().get('activity'))
    size = int(req.params.get('size') or req.get_json().get('size'))

    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {"activity": activity, "size": size})
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)

    # Get the response data from the orchestrator's output
    response_data = status.output

    # Construct the HTTP response with response data
    response = func.HttpResponse(f"runtime: {status.runtime_status}\n\noutput: {response_data}")

    return response

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> dict:
    parameter = context.get_input()
    activity = int(parameter.get("activity"))
    size = int(parameter.get("size"))
    response_times = []

    if activity == 1:  # DataFrame
        for i in range(2):
            start_activity_call = time.perf_counter()  # Record the start time of the activity call
            result = yield context.call_activity("activity1", size)
            end_activity_call = time.perf_counter()  # Record the end time of the activity call
            response_time = end_activity_call - start_activity_call
            response_times.append(response_time)

            logging.info(f"Activity1 Response Time: {response_time} seconds")

    output = {"response_times": response_times}
    result = yield context.call_activity("write_csv", output)
    return output

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="size")
def activity1(size: int) -> dict:
    data = np.random.rand(size)  # Create a Numpy array with one row and one column of size
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)  # Convert Numpy array to DataFrame
    start_serialization_time = time.perf_counter()  # Record the start time for serialization
    data_dict = data.to_dict()  # Convert to a serializable dictionary type
    end_serialization_time = time.perf_counter()  # Record the end time for serialization
    serialization_time = end_serialization_time - start_serialization_time
    dict_size = sys.getsizeof(data_dict)  # Measure the data size

    logging.info(f"Activity1 Serialization Time: {serialization_time} seconds")
    logging.info(f"Activity1 Data Size: {dict_size} bytes")

    return {"data": data_dict, "serialization_time": serialization_time, "data_size": dict_size}

@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="newblob/result.csv", connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="output")
def write_csv(output: dict, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    df = pd.DataFrame(output)
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    outputblob.set(csv_data)
    return "Inserted"
```

**Output:-**

Added The request body in the Postman like below and ran the Function:-

[image]

Here **Serialization Time is the Transfer time** and **Response time** is **given below**:-

[image]

***In Portal Function App after Deployment:-***

Called the below URL with request body in the Postman:-

```http
https://func-name.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/client_function
```

**Json Body to pass in the request:-**

```
{"activity": 1, "size": 100}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Application Insights :-**

```
traces
```

**Response Time:-**

[image]

**Transfer Time:-**

[image]